Codeigniter 4 - how to properly use entities
I haven't used entities much and I am not sure if I am using correctly.  I am trying to add favorite resorts to a table.  Here is my code:
function myFavorite() {
    $resortID = $this->request->getVar('resortID');
    $user_id = $this->current_user->id;
    
     if ($resortID && $user_id) {
        // Load the model
        $SknowedWeatherFavoritesModel = new \App\Models\SknowedWeatherFavoritesModel();

        // Create a new entity
        $SknowedWeatherFavoritesEntity = new \App\Entities\SknowedWeatherFavoritesEntity();
        $SknowedWeatherFavoritesEntity->sknowedWeather_id = $resortID;
        $SknowedWeatherFavoritesEntity->user_id = $user_id;

        // Save the entity
        if ($SknowedWeatherFavoritesModel->save($SknowedWeatherFavoritesEntity)) {
            return "Favorite added successfully.";
            die();
        } else {
            return "Failed to add favorite.";
            die();
        }
    } else {
        return "Missing resortID or user_id.";
        die();
    }
    
}

The above works.  It I click myFavorite button on a resort, it will add, say for exmaple, id (auto inc), resortID and user_id.
the problem I am facing it that if I hit the myFavorite button again, it adds another identical record except the auto inc is increase by 1.  I was reading the ->save will insert if new and update if already existing. How would I ensure no duplicate entry?  or am I doing this all wrong?
This is my db (unrelated fields removed);
CREATE TABLE `sknowedWeatherFavorites` (
  `sknowedWeatherFavorites_id` int NOT NULL,
  `sknowedWeather_id` varchar(17) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE 
utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `sknowedWeather` (
  `id` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

Relationships as follows;

Thank you for any pointers.

How's your schema ? Can you share details

@AkshayHegde add some more details.  Thank you.

please check UPDATING and CREATE @ Working with the Entity Class, as well as the concept of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists

you need to make sure your db table relations become unique, setting the right index(es)
